# how is output elasticity different from marginal product of a factor input?

Tags: production-function, elasticity

marginal product has been defined as the addition to total product given the employment of one more unit of a factor input.
output elasticity has been defined as the percentage change in output given percentage change in input.
how are they different? please explain.

Comment: Your definitions state the difference? I think you might simply have difficulties with understanding elasticity. In this case, have a look at the elasticity questions on this site, there are several with numerical examples

Comment: I dont have a problem with elasticity as a concept in itself... i know that elasticity is the degree of responsiveness of one variable to changes in another...i just feel the differences are not that much between marginal product and output elasticity... if you do understand, could you explain it to me?

Comment: Not sure how to explain beyond the definitions you stated. "*marginal product has been defined as the addition to total product given the employment of one more unit of a factor input*" This is measured in units of output. "*output elasticity has been defined as the percentage change in output given percentage change in input.*" This is measured in percentages. Otherwise they are about the same things.

Comment: if the differences are just changes in units, how are they different *concepts*?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. They are different in what they are different, and similar in what they are similar.

Comment: in other words, you dont understand either... its okay, lets hope there is someone out there who can help us both... :)

Comment: Ooo, damn, I sure got put in my place! Let us hope mistery savior arrives.

Comment: take it easy man... i am not here to fight with you... i just want an answer to my doubt...