# relation between elasticity of substituion and mrts

Tags: production-function, elasticity-of-substitution

elasticity of substituion has been defined as the as the percentage change in capital labour ratio given change in mrts.
but mrts itself tries to explain how a change in labour results in a change in capital... becuase it is the rate of substituion between the same.

why are they different? please explain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how is output elasticity different from marginal product of a factor input?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/56392/how-is-output-elasticity-different-from-marginal-product-of-a-factor-input)